SwiftUI contentView doesn't rerender after Binding object has changed its State variable
I'm trying to make my button "habitEggButton" disappear after being held using @State and @Binding across different files, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm still quite new to Swift, and so I'm not really sure all of the working parts work together.
Habit:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Habit : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var habitName: String
    var isDisplayed: Bool
}

HabitEggButton:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct HabitEggButton: View {
    @Binding var habit : Habit
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print(habit.habitName + " button tapped")
            if habit.isDisplayed {
                print("Yes")
            }
            else {
                print("No")
            }
        }) {
            Image("egg_uncracked")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
        }
        .supportsLongPress {
            habit.isDisplayed = false
            
            print(habit.habitName + " button held")
        }
    }
}

ContentView:
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
extension UIScrollView {  open override var clipsToBounds: Bool {   get { false }   set { }  } }

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fulfilled = 0
    @State private var numOfEggs = 3
    @State private var displayState = true
    @State private var displayHabit = " "
    
    @State var name = "Drink Water"
    @State var display = true
    
    @State var habit1IsDisplayed = true

    @State private var habits: [Habit] = [
            Habit(habitName: "Run", isDisplayed: true),
            Habit(habitName: "Fight", isDisplayed: true),
            Habit(habitName: "Jump", isDisplayed: true)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {        
        NavigationView {
            let chickenImageName = fulfilled == numOfEggs ? "chicken_in_egg" : "chicken_in_egg_sad"
            
            ZStack {
                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9294117647, green: 0.9294117647, blue: 0.9137254902, alpha: 1)).ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer().frame(maxWidth: 300)
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Settings tapped")
                        }) {
                            Image("settings")
                                .resizable()
                                .background(Color.clear)
                                .frame(width: 37, height: 37)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Image(chickenImageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
                    
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        HStack(spacing: -10) {
                            if numOfEggs == 0 {
//                                HabitEggButton(habit: false, habitName: "MyHabit", isDisplayed: true)
//                                    .opacity(0)
                                    Text("oops")
                            } else {
                                
                                ForEach($habits) { $habit in
                                    HabitEggButton(habit: $habit)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .offset(x: 25)
                    
                    Text(displayHabit)
                        .font(Font.custom("Inika-Bold", size: 26))
                        .opacity(displayHabit == "" ? 0 : 1)
                        .offset(y: 50)
                }
                .offset(y: -65)
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

SupportsLongPress (Custom Long Press Button):
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct SupportsLongPress: PrimitiveButtonStyle {
    /// An action to execute on long press
    let longPressAction: () -> ()
    
    /// Whether the button is being pressed
    @State var isPressed: Bool = false
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        
        // The "label" as specified when declaring the button
        configuration.label
        
            // Visual feedback that the button is being pressed
            .scaleEffect(self.isPressed ? 0.9 : 1.0)
        
            .onTapGesture {
                
                // Run the "action" as specified
                // when declaring the button
                configuration.trigger()
                
            }
        
            .onLongPressGesture(
                
                perform: {
                    
                    // Run the action specified
                    // when using this style
                    self.longPressAction()
                    
                },
                
                onPressingChanged: { pressing in
                    
                    // Use "pressing" to infer whether the button
                    // is being pressed
                    self.isPressed = pressing
                    
                }
                
            )
    }
    
}

/// A modifier that applies the `SupportsLongPress` style to buttons
struct SupportsLongPressModifier: ViewModifier {
    let longPressAction: () -> ()
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.buttonStyle(SupportsLongPress(longPressAction: self.longPressAction))
    }
}

/// Extend the View protocol for a SwiftUI-like shorthand version
extension View {
    func supportsLongPress(longPressAction: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
        modifier(SupportsLongPressModifier(longPressAction: longPressAction))
    }
}

I've tried making swapping the @Binding and @State values around, and I've debugged the holding button down with print statements. I see that the "isDisplayed" value does change, but the view does not rerender. I thought that because the habit object within the habitEggButton is @Binding that the contentView would refresh after the value changes. Any help would be great, thank you!

Actually you did well about your saying but I really did not understand why you thinking like its not refreshing. Because if you try to add this line code in your ZStack you will see its already watching changes.
           if habits.contains(where: { $0.isDisplayed == false  }) {
                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1)).ignoresSafeArea()
            } else {
                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9294117647, green: 0.9294117647, blue: 0.9137254902, alpha: 1)).ignoresSafeArea()
            }

I changed your code little bit but doing same thing.
struct HabitEggButton: View {
    @Binding var habit : Habit
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            habit.isDisplayed = false
            print(habit.habitName + " button tapped")
            if habit.isDisplayed {
                print("Yes")
            }
            else {
                print("No")
            }
        }) {
            Text(habit.habitName)
                .font(.title)
            Image(systemName: "camera")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
        }
        
    }
}

Maybe the problem is about your supportsLongPress gesture.

Thanks for the reply! Hmm, I've just edited the post and added the suppotsLongPress button code. I yoinked it off online but it seems to work as when I hold down on the button the terminal prints out that the button has been held. I'm a little confused cause I was expecting the button to disappear from the scrollView once isDisplayed turns false, but when I hold down the button it still persists in the view.

Never mind I figured it out, I was missing a conditional statement in the rendering stupid mistake lol. Thank for the help!
